# Difference resulting from position of print in loops

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

First question here.

I am picking up Python and have a question that may be quite basic.
I am trying to create this pattern with a nested loop:

```
x
x
x
xxx
```

With the code:

```
numbers = [1,1,1,3]
for count_x in numbers:
    output = ""
    for count in range(count_x):
        output +=x
    print(output)
```

My question is - why does my output change when I move the position of `print(output)`.

The code above works but when I align `print(output)` with the `for count_x in numbers:`, I only get "xxx", when I align `print(output)` to `output +=x`, I get the following:

```
x
x
x
x
xx
xxx
```

which is very odd because there are only 4 items in the list and it shows me 6 lines of output.

Could someone please help? Really puzzled. Thank yall very much.

Comment: When you move `print` to the right, you make it a part of the inner loop.

Comment: When `print(output)` is outside the for loop, it just prints the last thing that was assigned to `output`, which was `xxx`.

Comment: Thanks alot alec, I now understand why we can't put it outside. I don't see why it would print out 6 lines for the inner loop though. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between these two bits of code (fixing the `x/"x"` problem along the way - your code won't actually work as is unless you have a *variable* `x`):

```
# First:
numbers = [1,1,1,3]
for count_x in numbers:
    output = ""
    for count in range(count_x):
        output += "x"
    print(output)

# Second:
numbers = [1,1,1,3]
for count_x in numbers:
    output = ""
    for count in range(count_x):
        output += "x"
        print(output)
```

In the second, the `print` is done *inside* the loop that creates the string, meaning you print it out multiple times while building it. That's where your final three lines come from: `*`, `**` and `***`. This doesn't matter for all the previous lines since there's no functional difference. Printing a one character string at the end or after adding each of the one characters has the same effect.

In the first, you only print the string after fully constructing it.

You can see this effect by using a slightly modified version that outputs different things for each outer loop:

```
numbers = [1,1,1,3]
x = 1
for count_x in numbers:
    output = ""
    for count in range(count_x):
        output += str(x)
        print(output)
    x += 1
```

This shows that the final three lines are part of a *single* string construction (comments added):

```
1       \
2        >- | Each is one outer/inner loop.
3       /
4       \   | A single outer loop, printing
44       >- | string under construction for
444     /   | each inner loop.
```

---

In any case, there are better ways to do what you want, such as:

```
numbers = [1,1,1,3]
for count_x in numbers:
    print('x' * count_x)
```

You could probably also do it on one line with a list comprehension but that's probably overkill.